# Jekyll with GitHub Enterprise

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, github-enterprise

I'm following this guide to get me started with Jekyll: [Setting up your GitHub Pages site locally with Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/), but I'm doing this against GitHub Enterprise. My repo is at `https://github.company.com/myorg/myrepo`, and GitHub Pages are served from `https://pages.github.company.com/myorg/myrepo` (or `https://github.company.com/pages/myorg/myrepo`).

The step `bundle exec jekyll new . --force` in the tutorial created a simple template site, and I modified `_config.yml` to include this:

```
baseurl: ""
url: "https://pages.github.company.com/myorg/myrepo"
repository: "myorg/myrepo"
```

But after I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I see it going out to public GitHub:

```
Generating...
   GitHub Metadata: No GitHub API authentication could be found. Some fields may be missing or have incorrect data.
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/pages: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/contributors?per_page=100: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/users/myorg/repos?per_page=100&type=public: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
   GitHub Metadata: GET https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/releases?per_page=100: 404 - Not Found // See: https://developer.github.com/v3
```

Looking at this: [Repository metadata on GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.7/user/articles/repository-metadata-on-github-pages/), I figured I could override some GitHub metadata settings in `_config.yml` to point to GitHub Enterprise, so I added this:

```
github:
  hostname: github.company.com
  pages_hostname: pages.github.company.com
  api_url: https://api.github.company.com
  repository_url: https://github.company.com/myrepo/myorg
```

But it doesn't change anything, it still goes out to public GitHub API.

Looking at this: [github-metadata](https://github.com/jekyll/github-metadata), I tried overriding the API:

```
$ PAGES_API_URL="https://api.github.company.com" bundle exec jekyll serve
```

But it didn't work either.

The site does actually 'build', but if I go to `https://127.0.0.1:4000/` the site title link in there takes me to `http://github.com/pages/myorg/myrepo/`. How do I get it to actually use GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: you have to rename your repo name to: my_company.github.io and that's it

Comment: That's if I want to create a full user/org page right? I'm just trying to create a Project Page, `myorg/myrepo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/user/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages
Of course, make sure your version of GitHub Enterprise is correctly chosen.

> `http(s)://[hostname]/pages/<orgname>/<projectname>/`, or `http(s)://pages.[hostname]/<orgname>/<projectname>/` if subdomains are enabled.

You may also need to "enable" the github pages properly in your repositories settings page: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/user/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Answer (score 0):

One additional note to add here. Make sure that in the GitHub Pages section of your repository settings is marked as enabled. If you are using your Username.github.io repo, you will be forced to reference the main branch. You can find more info here: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/user/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/